# Error: Cannot read property 'logPurchase' of undefined when setting up React Native Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I'm trying to setup the React Native FBSDK for our app.  I followed the installation instructions for iOS.  Then tried to test it with the following snippet found in the documentation here (https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#analytics-for-apps) but modified for my app.

```
import FBSDK from 'react-native-fbsdk';
```

Then in the `componentDidMount`..

```
const {
    AppEventsLogger,
} = FBSDK;
console.log('AppEventsLogger.logPurchase', AppEventsLogger.logPurchase);
AppEventsLogger.logPurchase(15, 'USD', {'param': 'value'});
```

When I do, I see the `logPurchase` function in the React Native Debugger console (see screenshot), but immediately after when I try to invoke the function, I get the error `Cannot read property 'logPurchase' of undefined`. Also tested with other methods in that file like `logEvent` with same results.

Screenshot of logPurchase and error in console:

[image]

Anyone know why I might be getting this error, even though the function appears to be there?

Comment: same issue, you ever solve it?

Comment: @AlainGoldman I can't remember if I solved this or came up with a workaround. It's been a while, lol.